# "Направить обращение по одному из способов" - это правильно?

Tags: грамматика

На некоторых сайтах я встречаю следующую фразу. Если у вас есть вопросы, ... вы можете направить нам обращение по одному из способов, указанных в разделе «Контакты». Примеры таких сайтов: [https://www.google.com/search?q="обращение+по+одному+из+способов"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%22)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли составлена эта фраза? Не будет ли правильнее написать "направить нам обращение одним из способов"?